# A question about null sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ F: R^n \rightarrow R $ be a continuous function. Let $ S= F^{-1}(0) $. Is it true that the boundary of $ S $ has null Lebesgue measure? If it is no what happen if we suppose $ F $ smooth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem, I think due to Borel, which states that each closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is $F^{—1}(\{0\})$ for some *smooth* function $F$.

So the answer is no, taking $K^n$ where $K$ is a fat Cantor set.